# How to Print Raw SQL query of Magento 2 format?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, query, print

I am trying to print the raw SQL query of the below statement in Magento2 but am not able to do it. please find the statement

**`$connection  = $this->getConnection();`** // I am getting the connection
**`$tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::REQUESTED_TABLE);`** // getting the table
**`$data = ['is_legacy'=>1];`** // Update 'is_legacy=1'
**`$cond_val1 = 28;`** //for this id
**`$cond_val2 = 'sales_email_shipment_template';`** // for this code

**`$where = ['template_id = ?' => (int)$cond_val1, 'orig_template_code = ?' => $cond_val2];`**

**`$updatedResult = $connection->update($tableName, $data, $where);`**

**Note:** I am able to perform the operation correctly.
Here I want to log the above MySQL query in a separate log file in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to log the query as per your code, it may not possible. I would suggest going with below code for the update query:

Build up a special select:

```
$connection = $this->getConnection(); // I am getting the connection
$tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::REQUESTED_TABLE); // getting the table
$data = ['is_legacy'=>1]; // Update 'is_legacy=1'
$cond_val1 = 28; //for this id
$cond_val2 = 'sales_email_shipment_template'; // for this code

$where = 'template_id = ' . (int)$cond_val1 . 'and orig_template_code = "' . $cond_val2 . '"';

        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                false,
                $data
            )
            ->where($where);
```

please note that we did not select any table, we are using columns to pass thru field-value pairs, and using the conditions required to the update

translate above select as update query:

```
        $updateSelect = $connection->updateFromSelect(
            $select,
            $tableName
        );
        //echo $updateSelect; //you can use this variable for print the query
        $connection->query($updateSelect);
```

Now there are two ways to add logs in custom file:

1. Using custom logger class and set/define the custom log file:

Assuming your module is in `YourNamespace/YourModule`:

**A) Write Logger class in `Logger/Logger.php`:**

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{
}
```

**B) Write Handler class in `Logger/Handler.php`:**

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger;

use Monolog\Logger;

class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    /**
     * Logging level
     * @var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

    /**
     * File name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileName = '/var/log/myfilename.log';
}
```

**C) Register Logger in Dependency Injection `etc/di.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">myLoggerName</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**D) Use the logger in your Magento classes:**

This is done by Dependency Injection. Below you will find a dummy class which only writes a log entry:

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Model;

class MyModel
{
    /**
     * Logging instance
     * @var \YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Logger
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \YourNamespace\YourModule\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->_logger->info('I did something');
    }
}
```

2. Directly use the zend class and print the log in the custom file

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log'); 
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();  
$logger->addWriter($writer); 
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

Please let me know if this will help or you have any query

Comment: Hi @Nits by using the above and print the query I am getting this error:                         Notice: Array to string conversion in ../vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 1043
Magento\Framework\DB\Select->where() called at [app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Controller/UpdateOperation/ShippingTrackingEmail.php:53

Comment: In this statement we are getting array to string conversion notice: $where = ['template_id = ?' => (int)$cond_val1, 'orig_template_code = ?' => $cond_val2];

Comment: @shankarboss I have provided the reference code and logic, you need to make it work as per your requirement. I have just given an example, if you need an exact code that you can copy and past let me know. One thing doing this you will not learn M2.

Comment: @shankarboss Updated the where condition code in my answer. Please check and if you still facing any issue, let me know.

Comment: Hi @nits I already tried the updated one (on the same day) before you updated here but in that way we are not able to print the query.

Comment: the custom log part working as expected. for that I have give +1

Comment: Thanks..........

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
echo $updatedResult->getSelect();
```

or

```
echo $connection->getSelect();
```

may anyone work for you.

Comment: No. Those statements I tried but not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $resourceConnection;
    public function __construct(Context $context, ResourceConnection $resourceConnection)
    {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function runSqlQuery($table)
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        // $table is table name
        $table = $connection->getTableName('my_custom_table');
        //For Select query
        $query = "Select * FROM " . $table;
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($query);
        $this->_logger->log(print_r($result, true));
        $id = 2;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE id = $id ";
        $result1 = $connection->fetchAll($query);
        $this->_logger->log(print_r($result1, true));
        //For Insert query
        $tableColumn = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
        $tableData[] = [5, 'xyz', '20'];
        $connection->insertArray($table, $tableColumn, $tableData);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "`(`id`, `name`, `age`) VALUES (7,'mtm',33)";
        $connection->query($query);
        // For Update query
        $id = 1;
        $query = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET `name`= 'test' WHERE id = $id ";
        $connection->query($query);
        $query1 = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET `name`= 'test', `age` = 14 WHERE id = $id ";
        $connection->query($query1);
        // For Delete query
        $id = 1;
        $query = "DELETE FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE id = $id ";
        $connection->query($query);
    }
}
```